# Find height of object detection in tflite flutter

Tags: flutter, math, tflite

I am using flutter fluttter_tflite package i get output as  [{confidence: 0.9305985569953918, index: 509, label: computer keyboard}] when i checked pub dev it shows it is returning value of **Image classification**
but i also need height and width of the object how to get it?  in object detection it gives {
detectedClass: "hot dog",
confidenceInClass: 0.123,
rect: {
x: 0.15,
y: 0.33,
w: 0.80,
h: 0.27
}
} like this i need to get height and width ? how to get it

need height and width of the object how to get it?  in object detection it gives {
detectedClass: "hot dog",
confidenceInClass: 0.123,
rect: {
x: 0.15,
y: 0.33,
w: 0.80,
h: 0.27
}
} like this i need to get height and width ? how to get it

Comment: the `rect` contains the height and width. -- why did you paste your question twice into the question form?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when using (mobilenet) model

```
var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
    bytesList: image.planes.map((plane) {
      return plane.bytes;
    }).toList(), // required
    imageHeight: image.height,
    imageWidth: image.width,
    imageMean: 127.5, // defaults to 127.5
    imageStd: 127.5, // defaults to 127.5
    rotation: 90, // defaults to 90, Android only
    numResults: 5, // defaults to 5
    threshold: 0.1, // defaults to 0.1
    asynch: true // defaults to true
    );
```

after playing with code, I replace the "mobilenet" with YOLO

```
 var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnFrame(
    bytesList: image.planes.map((plane) {
      return plane.bytes;
    }).toList(), // required
    model: "YOLO",
    imageHeight: image.height,
    imageWidth: image.width,
    imageMean: 0, // defaults to 127.5
    imageStd: 255.0, // defaults to 127.5
    threshold: 0.1, // defaults to 0.1
    numResultsPerClass: 2, // defaults to 5
   // anchors:anchors, // defaults to [0.57273,0.677385,1.87446,2.06253,3.33843,5.47434,7.88282,3.52778,9.77052,9.16828]
    blockSize: 32, // defaults to 32
    numBoxesPerBlock: 5, // defaults to 5
    asynch: true // defaults to true
    );
```

I was getting the values of x,y,h,w

One last thing on documentation(flutter_tflite) they are using img, I think they have not updated the documentation it is an image in the code snippet they have provided for YOLO.

make sure to replace the YOLO model in the assets too.

if you are not sure from where you can get the YOLO model you can find it at this location.

C:\Users<YOUR SYSTEM NAME>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\example\assets